# Object as parameter and not string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing this for a school project how can I send parameters into klik function as an object and not string. Do I need to close my '' or is this not possible

```
var r = $('<input/>').attr({
                         type: "button",
                         //id: filmidata.arr[i].idi,
                         value: "+",
                            
                         class: "btn btn-outline-light"
                    }).attr('onclick','klik("filmidata.arr[i]")')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function calls as `onclick` HTML attributes are a bad practice (from the legacy web) as they require the function and the parameter to be defined in the global scope, and it also pollutes the HTML code.

You should write this instead :

```
var r = $('<input/>');
r.attr({
  type: "button",
  //id: filmidata.arr[i].idi,
  value: "+",
                            
  class: "btn btn-outline-light"
});

r.click(() => klik(filmidata.arr[i]));
```